# Multiple NIC card with different subnet

Tags: linux, networking, nic

Am using Cent OS 6.2 (64bit), I have 4 NIC interface, in that am trying to connect two NIC with different subnet,

em1 with 10.30.2.x series
em4 with 10.30.4.x series

Also I added route with /sbin/route add -net 10.30.4.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev em4

When I make the network device up "ifup em4" am not able to ping both the interfaces.

There is no IPtables running and selinux also disabled.

The same setup is working in one more DELL server, in that server reverse IP and IP forwarding is not enabled, even then its working. 
**Reverse IP & IP Forwarding**
 cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/em2/rp_filter
1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0

Any comments would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you setup a gateway for 10.30.4.x series also and please also paste the netstat -nr or route -n to paste the routing table.

Comment: Where are trying to ping from? Did you configure an IP address for the interfaces?

Comment: Hi, After disabling reverse path filtering and adding the route command it started working, please ignore my question. thanks.

Comment: Now, we enabled port mirroring in Cisco switch, after that pinging to the linux machine getting lost... Any thing to be done in linux side for port mirroring?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that ip addresses are actually setted on the interfaces, everything should work out, i would suggest to check network equipment on the way.
easiest way to test this is to use tcpdump -i any icmp and see if you actually receive the packets, this will also show you if your pong is going on the wrong interface.

hope that helps